# How to query external DataFactory in Pentaho Reporting

Tags: java, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I need to implement the following report in Pentaho Reporting using java:

```
Student 1
 - Calification 1
 - Calification 2
Student 2
 - Calification 1
 - Calification 2
...
```

The report receives all the information from the code. It has no access to the database. I am implementing this using Subreports. (This is a simplified example. I have other fields in the student, so I cannot use grouping)

I tried the following approach:

Create two Table Models for the DataFactory.

```
TypedTableModel model = new TypedTableModel();
model.addColumn("studentId", String.class);
model.addColumn("calification", String.class);
model.addRow("1", "10");
model.addRow("1", "10");
model.addRow("2", "5");

TypedTableModel model2 = new TypedTableModel();
model2.addColumn("studentId", String.class);
model2.addColumn("studentName", String.class);
model2.addRow("1", "Name 1");
model2.addRow("2", "Name 2");

TableDataFactory dataFactory = new TableDataFactory();
dataFactory.addTable("master-query", model2);
dataFactory.addTable("subreport-query", model);
```

Then, in the master report, I set query.name = master-query
in the subreport, I set query.name = subreport-query

What I get is:

```
Name 1
10
10
5

Name 2
10
10
5
```

In the subreport I managed to import the param "studentId" from the master report. I need to filter the califications by studentId in order to display only the califications from each student.
I need this:

```
Name 1
10
10

Name 2
5
```

How can I accomplish that?
Can I implement a query on "subreport-query"? How?

All the examples on the web query to JDBC connections using ${studentId}, but I need to query an external DataFactory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem in a different way.

Java dataFactory code:

```
TypedTableModel cal1= new TypedTableModel();
cal1.addColumn("calification", String.class);
cal1.addRow("10");
cal1.addRow("10");

TypedTableModel cal2= new TypedTableModel();
cal2.addColumn("calification", String.class);
cal2.addRow("5");

TypedTableModel model = new TypedTableModel();
model.addColumn("studentId", String.class);
model.addColumn("studentName", String.class);
model.addColumn("califications", TypedTableModel.class);
model.addRow("1", "Name 1", cal1);
model.addRow("2", "Name 2", cal2);

TableDataFactory dataFactory = new TableDataFactory();
dataFactory.addTable("master-query", model);
```

Pentaho subreport:

1) Imported the parent parameter called "califications". (Parameters - Import parameters)

2) Added a Scriptable Dataset with the following code (beanshell):

```
return dataRow.get("califications");
```

3) Right click in Scriptable Query -> Select query

Now the califications TypedTableModel is accesible from the subreport.